# How to dynamically change data-spy="affix" to data-spy="affix-top" in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this div in my html:

```
 <div class="row-fluid container-nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="130">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row-fluid">
               <?php nav_menu_primary(); ?>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I need to change the data-spy="affix" to data-spy="affix-top" to make the navigation not sticky on top when media screen is small.

JS:

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // if screen is resize
        delay(function() {

            var width = $(window).width();
           // document.write(width);
        if( width >= 550 && width <= 767 ) {
           $('.toopnav').css('data-spy','affix-top');
        } 

        }, pause );

       });

   $(window).resize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change .css() to [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('.toopnav').attr('data-spy','affix-top');
```

or use better approach  [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$('.toopnav').data('spy','affix-top');
```

Comment: Not working.. navigation still sticky. but, thank you for response.

Comment: where is class `toopnav` in html ?

Comment: Actually its not toopnav it tonav.

pls refer to my html above

I change jquery code as this. Sorry newbie here. Thanks
$('row-fluid container-nav').data('spy','affix-top');

Comment: Try `$('.row-fluid .container-nav').data('spy','affix-top');`

Comment: Try $('.row-fluid.container-nav').data('spy','affix-top');

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `data` attribute.. this is why `jquery.data` was introduce in latest version of jquery.

```
 $('.toopnav').data('spy','affix-top');
```

according to your html , i guess that should be

```
$('.container-nav').data('spy','affix-top');
```

Comment: Not working. 

Some suggested of this. working but problem is, desktop size screen also lost the stick navigation. Thanks.
$(window).off('.affix')
$("#topnav").removeData('affix').removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom')